# ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail not working for nougat device

Tags: android, file, android-7.0-nougat

```
Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(localUrl,
     MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Here bitmap gives me null value.

Comment: why it's not working? What's happening then? Did you debug? Did you google?

Comment: Its working fine for marshmallow and below version. But giving null bitmap for nougat.

Comment: For me it's working fine on nougat device. I have got Nexus 5X. Which device you're testing on? @PratikKukadia

Comment: Also check if there is any error trace.

Comment: file path : /storage/emulated/0/gosurvey/downloads/Video/fb93ced6-945d-4e62-87da-2fab3cd41518.mp4 
above is the file path from which I want to create a thumbnail.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I have Motoroloa Moto G(4) device

Comment: Is that path is correct ? Can you check with `new File("path").exists()` ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377129/thumbnailutils-createvideothumbnail-returns-null-for-existing-mp4-video) may help.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I have check the file exists it returns true.

Comment: Hmm.. Last thing I would check is stacktrace while calling this method. If there is any relevant error, share here.

Comment: E/MetadataRetrieverClient: failed to capture a video frame.

E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI: getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer

Answer (score 0):

The exact same condition I have faced, Only it was unable to create video thumbnail in higher version or high rated device. You are getting path of video in OnActivityResult something like this.

```
  if (requestCode == 3 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    String mimeType = getActivity().getContentResolver().getType(uri);
                    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(mimeType);
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    Log.e("PICTURE PATH", picturePath);
                    File file = new File(picturePath);
                    long length = file.length();
                    length = length / 1024;
                    long length2 = length / 1024;
                    if (length2 > 25) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You cannot upload file more than 25 MB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {

                        if (mimeType.contains("image")) {
                            Log.e("mimeType", mimeType);
                            Log.e("gif", picturePath);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), UploadImagePostActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("DESTINATION", picturePath);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            getActivity().finish();

                        } else if (mimeType.contains("video")) {

                            Log.e("mimeType", mimeType);
                            Log.e("Video path", picturePath);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), UploadVideoPostActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("VIDEO_DESTINATION", picturePath);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            getActivity().finish();

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Now you will get the path of video and you have to make video thumbnail after getting video path. sometime it may raise the problem of not getting correct path because some devices have different path hierarchy. so you have to save your thumbnail at a particular position and retrieve it back. code is give below.

```
// type 2 for video
    File uri = new File(filePath);

    //create thumbnail image
    thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
    img_tumbnail.setImageBitmap(thumb);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                thumbNailfile = savebitmap(thumb);
                Log.e("Thumbnail path", "" + thumbNailfile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

and the saving thumbnail file at specific path. now it will return the correct path of file.

```
// save bitmap into internal memory
public static File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) img_tumbnail.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
    //
    thumnailImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "123.jpg";
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "123.jpg");
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    fo.close();
    return f;
}
```